# Unit test on another pc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I want to **generate an executable from my unit test** in VS2015.
So another person on another computer without VS can start the test and see an output of the unit test.
(Which one is failed, which not)

Is this possible or should I manually write a tool for that?

I can't find anything on MSDN.

Comment: Are you using TFS (Team Foundation Server) also are you using MSTest or some other unit testing library like NUnit? Lastly does the program need to be run on another user's machine or do you really just need to give a way for some user outside of development the ability to initiate a test and see the result on demand (for example via a web portal)?

Comment: I think NUnit has a standalone test runner.  If you're using the Visual Studio tooling alone then it's probably going to continue to rely on Visual Studio.  (Though I suppose you could "fake it" by building a rudimentary test runner as a Console Application which simply references the Unit Test project(s) and executes the test methods directly.)

Comment: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5

Comment: @David if they are using TFS it has the ability to start a test from the web portal and run it on a test agent machine.

Comment: I'm not using TFS. I will try NUnit, thank you :)

Comment: You should use a CI server that builds your application and runs your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate an executable. as a matter of fact, all you need is to use your compiled dlls and the engine of the Unit Test runner you use to write your tests.

For instance:

- If you use NUnit, you can [use nunit-console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5)
- If you use MSTest, you can [use MSTest.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)

You will find a console version of your runner for pretty much any test engine. just run them against your compiled assemblies and voilà.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to achieve?

If it is for others to see test results then it would be a good idea to implement something like [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) to build and test your project. These products produce a nice dashboard that shows failing tests etc.